# Why my mesh is getting messed up?

Tags: modeling, weight-painting, vertex-paint

[image: Weight paint]

Is it because weight paint or is it something else? I have tried making it right with weight paint but it's still not working. Should I add more geometry to the leg part? Like adding few more vertices around the knee?

Comment: Looks like you should simply delete that extra face going from the foot to the bottom back.

Comment: could you share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5814" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5814/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mesh is super messy, you have a lot of inner faces + you need to join vertices to make nice quads and edge loops all around the legs.

[image]